# How to fix: 'Code signing operation failed (check that the identity you selected is valid error)' app submission error

Tags: ios, xcode, submit, xcode5, submission

When submitting my app to the app store I am getting that error.

My code signing section in 'Build Settings' is with a valid provisioning profile with the right bundle ID and the distribution certificate is also valid, also my Archive succeds.

What may have caused the problem is that I've changed my target's name, however this was happening before that so I don't think that's likely.

One thing I've noticed is that my file size when this error wasn't happening was of 1,2mb and now, without any major changes to its code or its files, it ha shrinked to about 600kb, I don't know if that's of any help.

I am using Xcode 5.02 and this app was cerated in it, not in an older version. If you have want me to provide anything more ask in the comments. From start, thanks.

Comment: I also had similar problems when attempting to submit my app using Xcode 5. I instead used the Application Loader and everything went smooth. https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Comment: @Jonathan I am, because of this error not being able to save it into a .ipa file, therefore I can't use the application loader, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build IPA for distribution with TestFlight with XCode 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109616/how-to-build-ipa-for-distribution-with-testflight-with-xcode-5)

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing a native iOS app, or are you using a cross-platform framework such as cordova or phonegap? Either way, if you have certain (in my case extraneous) files, it could lead to your problem. See: [How to build IPA for distribution with TestFlight with XCode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25109616/1449799)

I removed the following and then the problem was gone!

> Gruntfile.js, karma-e2e.conf.js, karma.conf.js, and the entire node_modules directory.